# using variable for urllib url causing unknown url type: '%22http' error

Tags: python-2.7, urllib

i am trying to pass a url to urllib with:

```
# a file with a url on each line
file_object = open('file.txt', 'r').xreadlines()
for line in file_object:
    print line # to check if it is getting the correct value 
    var = urllib.urlopen(line).read()
```

i am getting the error:

```
IOError: [Errno url error] unknown url type: '%22http'
```

i think `%22` means an escaped quotation mark.

so the url in the file is formatted as:

```
"http://www.test.com"
```

and the print statement is printing out:

```
"http://www.test.com"
```

and the creation of the `"`'s surrounding the url are generated with `"\"" + url + "\""` with the intention that urllib is being given the url in the format i thought it required.  but it seems the escape code is somehow being kept and urllib is not just treating the value as `"http://www.test.com"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are putting the URLs in the file with the quotation marks included, it is normal that this does not work, as quotation marks are only required for *literal strings* in the source code. Including the quotation marks in the file would be as if you write in the source code something like `"\"http://www.test.com/\""`. Removing the quotation marks from the file should solve the problem.

Comment: thank you, i think this worked (subsequent things in the code not working make me unsure, but that is probably unrelated).  i thought because urllib usually takes `"`'s around the url it required them in the value passed from the variable, but perhaps, as you suggest, this is only to assign the value properly. your explanation is better haha, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
    file_object = open('file.txt', 'r').xreadlines()
    for line in file_object:
        print line[1:-2] # to check if it is getting the correct value 
        var = urllib.urlopen(line[1:-2]).read()
```

line[1:-2] - simply strip one char on the beginning and two at the end of string